# Search sub string in particular column of cells if found paste whole row in new sheet in VBA

Tags: vba

I need in Col H if I search with GNOCCHI, it should found GNOCCHI L BASS & GNOCCHI L NOS.

Similarly NEW if i search it has to give New Circle 2 TX, New Circle 2 NOS Switch, NEW NOS VS

And in this example Column H my actual data it may wary .

data contains around 1000 rows

Please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Recorder:

- switch on the macro recorder
- apply an *AutoFilter* to the column
- use a text filter with the **Contains...** option
- switch off the macro recorder

A sample macro will be available